# How to use mapgroupwithstate to process all the batches arriving within 100 minutes and then generate an alert

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Basically I wanted to create a program using mapgroupwithstate where all the batches arriving within 100 minutes will be processed and after that a message will be generated futher it will start processing the next batches for another 100 min and generate a message an so on

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.yuvalitzchakov.com/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-spark-structured-streaming/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.